# Markov Chain and Steady States

Tags: markov-chains

I've been given the following problem and I want to know if the answer that I found makes sense.

A student center cafeteria has three fast-food centers - serving burgers, tacos, and pizza.A survey of students found the following information concerning lunch: 75% who ate burgers will eat burgers again at the next lunch, 5% will eat tacos next, and 20% will eat pizza next. Of those who ate tacos last, 20% will eat burgers next, 60% will stay with tacos, and 20% will eat pizza next.  Of those who ate pizza, 40% will eat burgers next, 20% tacos, and 40% pizza again. Assume  initially  that  one-third of students ate at each of the burger, taco, and  pizza stations.

Find the long-term behavior of the students regarding fast food.  Explain and interpret your findings.
What I found is the following matrix(approximate numbers):

$\begin{pmatrix} .55 & .55 & .55\\ .19 & .19 & .19 \\ .25 & .25 &.25 \end{pmatrix}$

So when I explain my findings I believe that this is a steady state and the matrix has reached equilibrium. So in the long run 55% of the students who ate burgers will eat burgers again the next day, 55% of the students that ate tacos will eat burgers the next day, 55% of the students that ate pizza will eat burgers the next day, so on and so forth. Does this sound accurate??

Comment: Using \\ to end paragraphs here or in a TeX document is a mistake. Both here and in a TeX document that is done by leaving a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

> So in the long run 55% of the students who ate burgers will eat
>   burgers again the next day

Not really. On the long run $55\%$ of the students will eat burgers.

---

The equation to calculate the steady state is

$A\cdot \vec x=\vec x$

Thus your result is a *vector* not a matrix.

$\vec x=\left(\begin{array}{} \frac59 \\ \frac{7}{36} \\ \frac14 \end{array}\right)$

Your results are approximately right. $\checkmark$

Comment: So it's not that in the long run 55% of the students that ate burgers will eat burgers again, just that in the long run 55% of students will eat burgers?

Comment: @Allison That´s right.

Comment: @Allison You´re welcome.